# Print final spaces of an argument

Tags: macros, white-space

I would like to print spaces that are at the end of an argument.

Here is my M(not)WE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\printspaceinarg[1]{%
    ]\texttt{#1}[%
}

\setlength\parindent{0em}


\begin{document}

\printspaceinarg{a     }

\printspaceinarg{ab    }

\printspaceinarg{abc   }

\printspaceinarg{abcd  }

\printspaceinarg{abcde }

\printspaceinarg{abcdef}

\end{document}
```

The output wanted is the following one.

```
]a     [

]ab    [

]abc   [

]abcd  [

]abcde [

]abcdef[
```

Is it possible or do I have to change the API of my macro ?

Comment: you need `\verb` (or at least `\obeyspaces`) but they can not normally be used in the argument of another command. Is there a reason you can't simply use `\verb|]a   [|` ?

Comment: No I can't because this will be used in a more "complex" macro. If it is simpler to change the API I will do it.

Comment: but that is the problem, and why I asked the comment before answering. Your question as asked could be answered by making `\printspaceinarg` act like `\verb`  but then it would also get the restrictions of verb: you would not be able to use it in the argument of another command.  If you want something that works in the argument or definition of another command then basically you are doomed as the spaces are gone before your command starts.

Comment: if your real use is take the argument as supplied and always pad to a specified length by adding spaces, that would be much easier than preserving spaces on input.

Comment: In that case what is the command to have exactly one space in `\texttt` ? How can I have give 3 as an argument and then oobtain the lenght of 3 spaces to be used for example with kern ?

Comment: `\ \ \ `  would be the simplest  or any kind of loop that took 3 and generated that  or just `\kern3\fontcharwd\font\`x` or ..

Comment: Why type 3 spaces and then count them to type an optional argument to make a loop that ... What is wrong with simply `\printspaceinarg{a\  \  \  \  }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\obeyspaces` when the `#1` parameter is read:

```
\def\printspaceinarg {\bgroup\obeyspaces\printspaceinargA}
\def\printspaceinargA #1{\egroup ]{\tt#1}[}

\printspaceinarg{a    }

\printspaceinarg{ab   }

\printspaceinarg{abc  }

\printspaceinarg{abcd }

\printspaceinarg{abcde}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the advice of David Carlisle, I propose the following solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\printspaceinarg[2][0]{%
    ]\texttt{#2}\kern#1\fontcharwd\font`x[%
}

\setlength\parindent{0em}


\begin{document}

\printspaceinarg[5]{a}

\printspaceinarg[4]{ab}

\printspaceinarg[3]{abc}

\printspaceinarg[2]{abcd}

\printspaceinarg[1]{abcde}

\printspaceinarg   {abcdef}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to state the total length to pad to, better than doing the computations yourself.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\padto}{O{0}m}
 {
  ]
  \texttt
   {
    #2
    \prg_replicate:nn { \int_max:nn { #1 - \tl_count:n { #2 } } { 0 } } { ~ }
   }
  [
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\padto[6]{a}

\padto[6]{ab}

\padto[6]{abc}

\padto[6]{abcd}

\padto[6]{abcde}

\padto[6]{abcdef}

\padto{a}

\padto[2]{a}

\padto[2]{ab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this proposition but the good API it the one of my question.

Comment: @projetmbc That's possible only if you change the category code of the space before absorbing the argument, but this means that the macro cannot be used in the argument to another macro. Spaces are compressed very early during tokenization and when TeX arrives at the macro expansion level, it has already performed the compression of spaces. Besides, editors have usually several ideas when breaking code across lines. As usual, making clearer what the final aim is could be helpful.

Comment: This is just for cosmetic uses : I have a macro to prints the signature of a macro in one technical doc. For example, I type `\IDmacro{mymacro}{1}{5}` and this prints `\mymacro[#opt]{#1..#5}`. I just want to align vertically hooks if I also indicate on the next line the same signature but for the star version of `\mymacro`.

Comment: The same signature can also appear with different names of macro.